# How to force webpack to load library using "Browser" method?

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I am trying to migration legacy project that uses bower and usemin, to webpack 4.
For the first step I want just create bundle of all JavaScript code. To do that I created `index.js` where I place all scripts in this form

```
window.moment = require('./bower_components/moment/moment.js');
require('imports-loader?define=>false,this=>window!' +
    './bower_components/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js');
```

I use imports and exports loaders for legacy libraries.
My problems is that some libraries trying to load/import dependencies like this

```
(function (root, factory) {
    "use strict";

    /*global define*/
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['moment'], factory);                 // AMD
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('moment')); // Node
    } else {
        factory(root.moment);                        // Browser
    }
}(this, function (moment) {
...
}
```

When webpack trying to load such library, second if clause give `true` and webpack trying to load dependency using `require()` statement.

Using `imports-loader?define=>false` I can force library do not try AMD method. But I can not figure out how to skip method that uses `require()`.
I tried to use  `imports-loader?define=>false,exports=>false` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to disable Node method? For example set exports to `false`.

I also tried to use `resolve.alias: {'libname', 'path/to/lib'}` option in webpack config. But this way in some cases leads to situation when webpack tried to import dependency two or more times and it breaks code.

Comment: Raf can you please tell me if my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `exports` to `false` :

```
require('imports-loader?define=>false,exports=>false,this=>window!' +
    './bower_components/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js');
```

This should makes the `typeof exports === 'object'` condition being false.